# Вылетает приложение при попытке использовать Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

Всем добрый вечер.
При попытке запустить приложение AVD выдаёт "Ufortunately, application has stoped."
Вот виновный класс:

```
    package com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations;

import android.util.Log;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Strategy {
    private Map<String, Currency> currencies = new HashMap<>();
    private final String URL_FORMAT = "http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily.aspx?date_req=%s";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
    private static final String REFERRER = "none";

    protected Document getDocument() throws IOException {
        return Jsoup.connect(String.format(URL_FORMAT, getDate())).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
    }

    public static String getDate() {
//        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
        return "11.07.2016";
    }

    public Map<String, Currency> getCurrencies() {
        Map<String, Currency> map = new HashMap<>();
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = getDocument();
            String e = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "data").get(0).getElementsByTag("td").text();
//            System.out.println(e);
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(e, " ");
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String validToken = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                if (validToken.length() == 3 && areDigits(validToken)) {
                    Currency currency = new Currency();
                    currency.setdCode(validToken);
                    currency.setCode(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    currency.setForAmount(Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken()));
                    String s = null;
                    while (true) {
                        if ((s = stringTokenizer.nextToken()).matches("^[0-9,]+$")) break;
                    }
                    currency.setRate(Double.parseDouble(s.replace(",", ".")));
                    currency.setDate(getDate());
                    map.put(currency.getdCode(), currency);
                    Log.d("adding to array", currency.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("e", e.toString());
        }
        return map;
    }

    private boolean areDigits(String validToken) {
        char[] ch = validToken.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ch) if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вот виновный метод:

```
 protected Document getDocument() throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(String.format(URL_FORMAT, getDate())).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
}
```

Вот вывод на консоль:

```
    04/21 22:13:44: Launching app
$ adb shell am startservice com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
$ adb shell am start -n "com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter/com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter | com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter | com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter.test
Connecting to com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8661', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8661', transport: 'socket'
```

=============

Стектрейс (если это он):

```
04-21 07:15:51.304 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10062: Read-only file system
04-21 07:15:51.304 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
04-21 07:15:51.305 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-21 07:15:51.399 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter
04-21 07:15:51.723 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter D/exception: catched
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-21 07:15:51.933 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:651)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Strategy.getDocument(Strategy.java:24)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Strategy.getCurrencies(Strategy.java:36)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.operations.Converter.prepareDB(Converter.java:28)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.xpendence.development.currencyconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-21 07:15:51.934 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-21 07:15:51.940 24040-24075/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                                             [ 04-21 07:15:51.943 24040:24040 D/         ]
                                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b7250, tid 24040
04-21 07:15:51.954 24040-24040/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter D/Atlas: Validating map...
04-21 07:15:51.992 24040-24075/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 07:15:51.993 24040-24075/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-21 07:15:52.006 24040-24075/com.xpendence.development.currencyconvarter D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Вангую что в стектрейсе будет сетевая операция в UI thread.

Comment: Добавил стектрейс в пост. Я тут выяснил, что нельзя в главном треде использовать ничего, кроме UI. NetworkOnMainThreadException — это оно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя выполнять сетевые запросы в главном потоке. Если сервер будет отвечать долго, приложение зависнет. Поэтому Android просто не позволяет этого делать, выбрасывая исключение [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Сетевой запрос можно вынести в [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) или [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Естественно, использование асинхронных задач потребует изменений в логики работы кода.

```
class FetchDocumentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
    private String url;
    private String userAgent;
    private String referrer;

    public FetchDocumentTask(String url, String userAgent, String referrer) {
        this.url = url;
        this.userAgent = userAgent;
        this.referrer = referrer;
    }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return Jsoup.connect(String.format(URL_FORMAT, getDate()))
            .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
            .referrer(REFERRER)
            .get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
        Strategy.setDocument(doc);
    }
}


new FetchDocumentTask(Strtegy.URL_FORMAT, Strategy.USER_AGENT, Strategy.REFERRER).execute();
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что во избежание исключения достаточно запихнуть в асинктаск только один метод, который использует соединение?

Comment: Или просто Strategy унаследовать от AsyncTask и поправить логику?

Comment: Достаточно метода, который непосредственно использует соединение. Но класс Strategy или использующий его код должны быть спроектированы с учётом того, что данные приходят асинхронно.