# Не работают методы у класса HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

```
String myURL = new String("http://4pda.ru");
    textViewSendText.setText("Hello");
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        textViewSendText.setText("1");
        URL url = new URL(myURL);
        textViewSendText.setText("2");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        textViewSendText.setText("3");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        textViewSendText.setText("4");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        connection.connect();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        textViewSendText.setText(Integer.toString(responseCode));
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

    }
    catch (Exception e){


    }
    finally {

    }
```

Пытаюсь сделать простейший запрос, но ничего не происходит. Программа останавливается на `connection.getOutputStream` или на `connect`.
Пытался запускать с реального устройства и с эмулятора - одно и то же происходит.
В манифесте прописал все что нужно, ничего не помогает.

вот вывод при нажатии на кнопку:

```
    05-24 15:54:20.466 22553-22553/? W/Zygote: mz_is_rooted false
05-24 15:54:20.469 22553-22553/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-24 15:54:20.743 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator E/System: stat file error, path is /data/app/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator-2/lib/arm64, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-24 15:54:20.747 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-24 15:54:20.878 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-24 15:54:21.264 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

                                                                           [ 05-24 15:54:21.264 22553:22590 I/         ]
                                                                           elapse(include ctx switch):3363 (ms), eglInitialize
05-24 15:54:21.264 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-24 15:54:21.275 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: Get enable program binary service property (1)
05-24 15:54:21.275 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
05-24 15:54:21.277 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 169916, program map length is 152.
05-24 15:54:21.277 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 54, and path is /dev/ashmem�.
05-24 15:54:21.277 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(54).
05-24 15:54:21.297 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-24 15:54:21.338 22553-22590/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 12143
05-24 15:55:00.061 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator I/System.out: open:http://4pda.ru
05-24 15:55:00.066 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=4pda.ru; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
05-24 15:55:00.066 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo( app_uid:10117
05-24 15:55:00.066 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() uid prop:
05-24 15:55:00.066 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() getuid():10117
05-24 15:55:00.066 22553-22553/com.example.uncolor.yandextranslator D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
```

Comment: я думаю здесь куда обширнее проблемы. Начиная от того, что возможно у вас запрос выполняется в потоке UI, ну или вы пытаетесь обновить виджет TextView непосредственно из другого потока

Comment: Я новичок в android. Я был бы благодарен, если вы объясните мои ошибки

Comment: Код выполняется в методе onClick

Comment: Покажите полный стек-трейс.

Comment: Добавил все, что было

Comment: Добавьте в ```catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace() } ``` и после этого обновите стек-трейс в вопросе. Вы ловите эксепшен, но никак его не обрабатываете. Поэтому и нет в логах ошибок. Но чую, что там будет NetworkInUIThreadException =)

Comment: А как тогда эту ошибку исправлять?

Comment: Ну вы сначало проверьте, та ли это ошибка. Если да, то решается выносом работы с сетью в бэкграунд поток. Посмотрите вот этот [урок](https://metanit.com/java/android/15.1.php)

Comment: Да, вы, судя по всему, были правы
Там появилось исключение android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вылетает приложение при попытке использовать Jsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656916/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-jsoup)