# Почему происходит и как избавится от NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android, rxjava

Делаю запросы к `Github api` для получения пользователей при вводе каждого следующего символа в `EditText` метод `onNextSearch()`. Ловлю `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. 
Я использую `RxJava` и как мне кажется запросы к сети должны выполняться не в `MainThread`.

```
private Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.empty();

    @Override
    public void onNextSearch() {

        if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        subscription = model.getUsers(view.getUserName())
                .subscribe(new Observer<GitResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        view.showError(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(GitResponse gitResponse) {
                        if (gitResponse != null ) {
                            view.showUsers(gitResponse.getItems());
                        } else {
                            view.showEmptyList();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

---

```
 @Override
    public Observable<GitResponse> getUsers(String name) {
        return apiInterface.getUsers(name)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вылетает приложение при попытке использовать Jsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656916/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-jsoup)

Comment: Я использую RxJava для того чтобы не выполнять это в главном потоке.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev обратите внимание что тут вопрос касается не только андроида, но и rxjava. Это значительно влияет на решение.

Answer (score 4):

Если не указывать явно в каком потоке должен выполняться код в `Observable`, то он будет выполняться в потоке, исполняющем инициализацию оного. В вашем случае это главный, `UI` поток.

Вам надо явно указать в каком потоке создавать `Observable` так:

```
subscription = model.getUsers(view.getUserName())
   //указываем поток в коем будет исполнен запрос в сеть
   .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
   //указываем поток, в котором будут вызваны колбэки
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread())
```