# NetworkOnMainThreadException rxjava

Tags: java, jsoup, rxjava

Есть такой код

```
 jsoupClient.getNewsForCategory("/politics/")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<News>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<News> news) {
                            newsView.showNews(news);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        }
                    });
```

в методе getNewsForCategory получаю ошибку на строчке

```
  Document politic = Jsoup.connect(category).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

хотя запускаю в дочернем потоке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вылетает приложение при попытке использовать Jsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656916/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-jsoup)

Comment: меня интересует почему такое поведение с rxjava а не как делать AsyncTask

Comment: Потому, что выбрасывающий ошибку `Jsoup.connect(category)` не относится к RxJava. Не знаю, как конкретно написан метод `getNewsForCategory()`, но подозреваю, что RxJava включается в процесс только в самой последней его строке, в момент выполнения `return`.

Comment: Точно,спасибо...